# Автоматизация тестирования

Tags: тестирование

Подскажите, какие программы существуют для записи действий пользователя и последующего их повторения, с возможностью настройки количества тестов, задержек итд и наличием лога?

Сам для этой цели использовал TestComplete, но мне кажется он избыточен для данной задачи, минусом является и что, что он платный.

Comment: Какого рода тестирование? Какой UI требуется тестировать?

Comment: UI на WPF, но основной задачей является тестирование стабильности работы других компонентов системы, которые дергаются через этот UI

Answer (score 2):

Своими глазами на одной из презентаций видел майкрософтовскую штуку из Team Foundation. Действия пользователя пишутся в лог, плюс, пишется видео с экрана ну и все такие стандартные фичи. Отличительная супер-особенность: в случае падения к багрепорту прикрепляется стек трейс и какие-то ещё дампы, которые позволяют в точности восстановить состояние программы.

Есть возможность записывать наборы действия для автоматического тестирования.

---

Штука, действительно, очень классная. Но, к сожалению, заметный профит будет только в том случае, если вся разработка ведётся именно в околостудийно среде. Ну и финансовый вопрос, разумеется.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, пригодится:

- [тестирование пользовательского интерфейса](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd286726.aspx);
- и конкретно, [создание записи действий](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd286647.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно тестировать UI могу посоветовать Sikuli (http://sikuli.org/). Скрипты пишутся на облегченном питоне. Специальная ИДЕ вставляет в код картинки по которым нужно кликнуть/подождать и т.д.

Answer (score -1):

Одно из последних решений, стремительно набирающих обороты, Katalon Studio.

1. **Бесплатный**.
2. Web, mobile, API
3. Репозитории объектов, кейвородов, подключение к БД и проч.
4. Java, Groovy

[Офф.сайт](https://www.katalon.com/)
[Документация](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD)